# Are GPU resources created under DirectX 12 guaranteed zero-initialized?

Tags: memory, initialization, directx-12

It's surprisingly hard to find information about this; does DirectX 12 guarantee that fresh resource allocations will be be completely zeroed before they're accessed by the compute/graphics pipelines?

Comment: I believe for security reasons on PC, the memory will be zero'd. That said, it's largely left as an implementation detail. For example, with Xbox One shared memory they aren't usually zero-filled before use.

Comment: Great, thank you :). So it'd still be best to manually zero-initialize? It doesn't feel like much extra code to zero things the first time they're accessed by the application.

Comment: In most use cases, you don't really care about 0-filled resources. You really need to set all values or do explicit ``Clear`` operations for render targets.

Comment: Yeah, thinking about it now there's no reason for something to stay uninitialized besides missed pixels during rasterization, and like you said the `Clear()` function exists for those anyways. Thanks for the help :)